# Apply a filter which reads all traffic apart from DNS and TCP using tcpdump

Tags: packet, tcpdump, packet-capture, bpf

I tried these commands:

1.tcpdump -r bpf-pcap.pcapng -w op2.txt proto not dns and not tcp

2.tcpdump -r bpf-pcap.pcapng -w op2.txt proto not dns and tcp

None of these are correct. I also checked the manual page but couldn't find what's wrong.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
tcpdump -r bpf-pcap.pcapng -w op2.pcap not port 53 and not tcp
```

Note `-w` doesn't write a text file but a binary file with the raw packets.